# R: Grouping by values up to a threshold

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with detection times for tagged fish.  I need to group it based on the tagID and the detection event, which is every detection for an individual tag, until it is absent for a period longer than a threshold time.

Here's an example dataset:

```
set.seed (999)
df <- data.frame (tag_id = c(rep("3DD.01",8),rep("3DD.04",24),rep("3DD.02",18)),
  absent_time = rchisq (50, 5))
max_time <- 7 #threshold value
```

I can build it the loop below, but it is too inefficient to run the full (1.6 million line) dataset.  The `df$count` column delineates the group.

```
vec_count <- rep (1,50)
for(i in 2:nrow(df)){
  if (df$tag_id[i] != df$tag_id[i - 1]){
    tmp <- vec_count[i -1] +1
  } else if (df$absent_time[i - 1] < max_time){
    tmp <- vec_count[i - 1]
  } else{
    tmp <- vec_count[i - 1] +1
  }
  tmp
  vec_count[i] <- tmp
}
df$count <- vec_count
```

Is there any way I can vectorize this and avoid running an 8-hour loop?  I get so close with mutate and piping, but no success yet.

Thanks for any help you're able to provide!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your calculation appears to depend on the immediately preceding row, I'm not clever enough to vectorize your task. Some suggestions are to check out `dplyr` functions `lag` and [the other window functions](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/window-functions.html).

(**UPDATE**: I add a solution using `dplyr` and some of the window functions -- see solution #3 -- I leave the other solutions up as they may still be useful).

One thing I assume is that your current solution is correct (but slow) -- please just check that it is doing the thing you think it is doing.

Here are 3 solutions.

1.) Don't repeatedly access a data.frame through a for loop.

Rather than access components of your data.frame using `df$tag_id` and `df$absent_time`,  use two vectors instead -- that is, use separate vectors for `tag_id` and `absent_time`. In general, accessing data.frames is more costly than accessing a matrix or vectors. Here is the solution. This will save a lot of time, but it still probably takes too long.

```
tag_id = df$tag_id
absent_time = df$absent_time
vec_count <- rep (1, length(tag_id))
for(i in 2:length(tag_id)){
  if (tag_id[i] != tag_id[i - 1]){
    tmp <- vec_count[i -1] +1
  } else if (absent_time[i - 1] < max_time){
    tmp <- vec_count[i - 1]
  } else{
    tmp <- vec_count[i - 1] +1
  }
  vec_count[i] <- tmp
}
df$count2 <- vec_count
```

2.) Your loop is simple enough to where you can get a fast C++ version using Rcpp in not much time at all. I am not a C++ programmer but was able to get this working in a few minutes. I would refer you to [Hadley Wickham's excellent chapter here](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Rcpp.html). If your actual dataset is more complex than what you gave, just be aware about things like how missing values are handled.

```
library(Rcpp)
cppFunction("IntegerVector fastloop(CharacterVector tag_id, 
                       NumericVector absent_time, 
                       int max_time) {
      // Create a vector filled with 1s
      int vec_size = tag_id.length();
      IntegerVector vec_count (vec_size, 1);
      // Go through your loop: starts at 0 in C++
      for (int i = 1; i < vec_size; i++) {
        int tmp = 0;
        if (tag_id[i] != tag_id[i - 1]) {
          tmp = vec_count[i - 1] + 1;
        } else if (absent_time[i - 1] < max_time) {
          tmp = vec_count[i - 1];
        } else {
          tmp = vec_count[i - 1] + 1;
        }
        vec_count[i] = tmp;
      }
      return vec_count;
}")
# Will take a few seconds to compile

df$count3 <- fastloop(df$tag_id, df$absent_time, 7)
identical(as.integer(df$count), df$count3)
```

**UPDATE**
3.) Here is the `dplyr` solution that doesn't need loops.

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>%
  mutate(
    # Create 2 lagged variables (lag defaults to 1 period)
    lag_tag = lag(tag_id),
    lag_absent = lag(absent_time),
    # Create a 1/0 variable indicating whether we add 1 or not
    plus_1 = ifelse(tag_id != lag_tag, 1, 
                    ifelse(lag_absent < max_time, 0, 1)),
    # First row will be NA -- replace with 1
    plus_1 = replace(plus_1, 1, 1),
    # Use cumsum function on plus_1
    cum_count = cumsum(plus_1)
  )

identical(df$cum_count, df$count) # TRUE
```

I put your current for loop and my three solutions into functions and try a larger randomly generated dataset to demonstrate the performance improvements. Sorry for the awkward `microbenchmark` statement . . .

```
old_solution <- function(x) {
  vec_count <- rep (1, nrow(x))
  for(i in 2:nrow(x)){
    if (x$tag_id[i] != x$tag_id[i - 1]){
      tmp <- vec_count[i -1] +1
    } else if (x$absent_time[i - 1] < max_time){
      tmp <- vec_count[i - 1]
    } else{
      tmp <- vec_count[i - 1] +1
    }
    vec_count[i] <- tmp
  }
  return(vec_count)
}


new_solution <- function(tag_id, absent_time) {
  vec_count <- rep (1, length(tag_id))
  for(i in 2:length(tag_id)){
    if (tag_id[i] != tag_id[i - 1]){
      tmp <- vec_count[i -1] +1
    } else if (absent_time[i - 1] < max_time){
      tmp <- vec_count[i - 1]
    } else{
      tmp <- vec_count[i - 1] +1
    }
    vec_count[i] <- tmp
  }
  return(vec_count)
}

dplyr_solution <- function(x) {
  x <- x %>%
    mutate(
      # Create 2 lagged variables (lag defaults to 1 period)
      lag_tag = lag(tag_id),
      lag_absent = lag(absent_time),
      # Create a 1/0 variable indicating whether we add 1 or not
      #  based on the condition you specified. 
      plus_1 = ifelse(tag_id != lag_tag, 1, 
                      ifelse(lag_absent < max_time, 0, 1)),
      # First row will be NA -- replace it with 1
      plus_1 = replace(plus_1, 1, 1),
      # Use cumsum function on plus_1
      cum_count = cumsum(plus_1)
    )
  return(x$cum_count)
}

set.seed (999)
# Imagine that I am creating unique IDs and not just repeating the same 3
df2 <- data.frame (tag_id = rep(c(rep("3DD.01",8),rep("3DD.04",24),rep("3DD.02",18)), 1000),
                  absent_time = rchisq (50000, 5))
max_time <- 7 #threshold value


library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(old_solution(df2), 
               new_solution(df2$tag_id, df2$absent_time),
               fastloop(df2$tag_id, df2$absent_time, 7),
               dplyr_solution(df2),
               times = 20L)

Unit: milliseconds
                                      expr       min         lq        mean     median        uq       max neval
                         old_solution(df2) 3544.8781 3702.99770 4076.295815 3771.94990 3995.6506 6849.6148    20
 new_solution(df2$tag_id, df2$absent_time) 2006.9711 2177.62850 2470.002845 2260.42390 2320.6644 4147.8885    20
  fastloop(df2$tag_id, df2$absent_time, 7)    1.4835    1.64955    2.242745    2.06805    2.6967    3.7357    20
                       dplyr_solution(df2)    8.0995    8.98240   13.660475   13.42025   17.1172   22.4442    20
 cld
   c
  b 
 a  
 a
```

As you can see, the `Rcpp` and `dplyr` solutions are pretty fast.

Comment: Added a solution using dplyr.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! I was able to make it work with the dplyr method, i'll be sure to take some time to read your reference too.